# Heap Algorithmic Issue

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, heap

I am having this algorithmic problem that I want to discuss about. Its not
      about find a solution but about optimization in terms of runtime. So here it is:

> Suppose we have a race court of *Length L* and a total of *N cars* that participate 
>     on the race. The race rules are simple. Once a car overtakes an other car the second 
>     car is eliminated from the race. The race ends when no more overtakes are possible 
>     to happen.
>     The tricky part is that the k'th car has a starting *point x[k]* and a
>     *velocity v[k]*. The points are given in an ascending order, but the velocities 
>     may differ.

What I've done so far:

> Given that a car can get overtaken only by its previous, I calculated the time
>     that it takes  for each car to reach its next one
>
> ```
> t = (x[i] - x[i+1])/(v[i] - v[i+1])
> ```
>
> and I insert these times onto a min heap in *O(n log n)*.
>     So in theory I have to pop the first element in *O(logn)*, find its previous, 
>     pop it as well , update its time and insert it in the heap once more, much 
>     like a priority queue. My main problem is how I can access specific points of a 
>     heap in O(log n) or faster in order to keep the complexity in O(n log n) levels.
>     This program should be written on Haskell so I would like to keep things simple
>     as far as possible

EDIT: I Forgot to write the actual point of the race. The goal is to find the order in which cars exit the game

Comment: And what part of the assignment are you having trouble with? Also @user0000000 as I read it he's trying to write a Haskell program, which would be on-topic.

Comment: The problem statement does not mention what you have to do. It just describes the race. Do you have to simulate all the overtakes or just calculate the time at which the race ends.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal you 're right. I forgot to write the actual point of the race . The programm should return the order in which the cars exit the race

Comment: I don't understand: why do you want to access a specific point of the heap?